# Regex optional non-regex group match

Tags: php, regex, csv

Say I have the following, as input:

```
Tonic,Love,(Original,Mix),house,dance,ton!c
```

Here are the rules I am trying to get:

1. All commas seperate an individual keyword, except when #2 is true.
2. Commas have no effect between round brackets.

   - All round brackets group keywords as one keyword.

I have the following regex right now:

```
#([\(?.*?\)])|(.*?),#
```

I end up with results like this:

```
Tonic
Love
(Original
Mix)
house
dance
```

It's the same as splitting by the comma, except I have lost the last keyword `ton!c`. I do not require this to all happen in one regex, but it is preferred.

Comment: Replace last comma in regexp with `,|$` in order to not loose last value.

Comment: Haven't you also lost (Original,Mix) as this needs to be a SINGLE keyword based on #2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple one : `\([^\)]*\)|[^,]*` should work.

Comment: This works (almost) exactly as I need it to. The only thing I changed was the last `*` to a `+` to remove empty matches.

Answer (score 1):

You could split on:

`/,(?![^(]*\))/`

or match all with:

`/\([^)]*\)|[^,()]*/`

at least for your examples.

I.e:

```
$array = preg_split('/,(?![^(]*\))/', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
"(\([^)]+\))|([^(][^,]*)(,(\([^)]+\))|([^(][^,]*))*"
```

This catches all groups at once.